# CSS Menu Drop Down Disapear

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, z-index

http://ableworkforcetraining.com/

I have a Wordpress 3.5 with the Woo Themes: White Light

It appears my drop down CSS menu is having issues with the vslider plugin. Menu drops away when you hit the bottom of the course menu.

I think it may be z-index issues. I have read a lot of posts and I feel like I have z-index:9999; just about everything menu related.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am out of ideas.

Thanks in advance!

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a z-index, but don't know exactly why.

You have this:

```
#navigation .nav li ul { z-index: 999; }
```

Make that z-index: 9999; and the problem go away... Why does it doesn't work with 999? Probably because you or someone else is messing too much with z-index =(

Edit: check your css code. You will eventually find something (probably related to the slider) with a high z-index, like 999 or 1000, because if you change your #navigation .nav li ul z-index to 1001 it already works.

Also, that selector looks 'maybe' too specific to my taste. You can probably live with .nav li ul or #navigation li ul.

Edit2: Reading your question again, you say you have 9999 for z-index for about anything related to menus. WHYYYY??? Trust me, you really don't need that. Actually, if you're not messing with z-index in your website, a z-index of 100 is already too much. Making something a 9999 z-index may only bring you problems in the future.

Promise me you'll search your .css files for all z-index entries and correct that?

Comment: Thank you, so much! You found the one (correct z-index) that I did not mistakenly add 9999 to :)

Comment: yes it works, but i don't like the habit of someone to put a very big z-index. it shouldn't be a random big number. the first is z-index:0, the second z-index:1, the third z-index:2 and so on..don't use 9999999 for just 2-3 layers..it makes no sense, because when you'll have to edit it, you'll need extra work to fix the things.

Comment: That's what I was trying to explain but he decided to literally ignore it. Hopefully he'll consider that in future projects.